# getAssociatedProducts - override function but numeric field ordering alphabetically

Tags: product-collection

I am extending  Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped  with a function similar to  getAssociatedProducts()  called

getAssociatedProductsWithSort($product = null,$sortField="name",$direction="ASC")

so to order the simple products under a grouped product.  The difference is this:

```
<?php
public function getAssociatedProductsWithSort($product = null,$sortField="name",$direction="ASC",$defaultSort="capacity_grams",$defaultDirection="ASC"){

        $associatedProducts = array();

        if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            $this->setSaleableStatus($product);
        }

        $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection($product)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
            //->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)))
            ->addAttributeToSort($sortField,$direction)
            ->addAttributeToSort($defaultSort,$defaultDirection)
            ;

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $associatedProducts[] = $item;
        }

        $this->getProduct($product)->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);

    return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);

} //end-o-func
?>
```

However, the problem is that the values in my chosen field (Created via the admin) are numbers but the ordering is happening alphabetically:  e.g.

1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Can I force addAttributeToSort() to do it numerically?  I have tinkered with using a CAST in the call but to no avail.  I have also tried doing but this didn't work either.

```
<?php
    $collection->reset("order")
        ->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr("CAST( ".$sortField." AS SIGNED ) ".$direction))
                ;
?>
```

Comment: Also, can someone tell me how to set syntax highlighting for php code?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Having looked through the error logs I noticed that the attribute was not coming through in the select statement.  To resolve this "Used for Sorting in Product Listing" needed to be set to "Yes".

Also there is an error in the collection->reset code above.  The final function code is this:

```
<?php
public function getAssociatedProductsWithSort($product = null,$sortField="name",$direction="ASC",$numericField=false){

        $associatedProducts = array();

        if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            $this->setSaleableStatus($product);
        }

        $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection($product)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
             ->addAttributeToSelect($sortField)
            ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
            //->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)))
            ->addAttributeToSort($sortField,$direction) //this sorts numbers alphabetically
            ;
       if($numericField){ //force number sort
            $collection->getSelect()->reset("order");
            $collection->getSelect()->order("CAST(`".$sortField."` AS SIGNED) ".$direction);
        }

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $associatedProducts[] = $item;
        }




        $this->getProduct($product)->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);

    return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);

} //end-o-func

?>
```

Comment: Hope this helps other people